# Proving differentiability at x0 using continuity at x0

Tags: derivatives, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

[image: Question]
This is a question I haven't been able to complete for some time now. I have shown below what I have tried so far and I need to know the following,

1.Am I on the right track?

2.How do I show that f' is differentiable at x0?

[image: My Answer]

Also I would appreciate some hints on how I could complete part (b) of the question.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the question. That should be $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Comment: Your third implication means that $f'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_0} [f(x)-f(x_0)] = 0$ doesn't imply that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=0$. Why? Well, what happens if $f(x) = |x|$ and $x_0=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$, then
$$\frac{|f(x)-a_0 - a_1(x-x_0)|}{|x-x_0|} < \epsilon$$
i.e.
$$|f(x)-a_0 - a_1(x-x_0)| < \epsilon |x-x_0| < \epsilon \delta$$
Then
$$|f(x)-a_0| - |a_1(x-x_0)| < |f(x)-a_0 - a_1(x-x_0)| < \epsilon\delta$$
So
$$|f(x)-a_0| < \epsilon \delta + |a_1| \delta$$
Now we may take $\delta$ to be smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{|a_1|}$, so we see that
$$|f(x)-a_0| < 2\epsilon$$
That is, $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)-a_0 = 0$. Thus $f(x_0) = a_0$ by continuity.

Now that we have this, we see that
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-a_0 - a_1(x-x_0)}{x-x_0} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - a_1 = 0$$
i.e.
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = a_1$$
The left-hand side is $f'(x_0)$, which exists and is equal to $a_1$.